# "There are two apartments fitting you perfectly."

Tags: sentence-construction, clauses, infinitive-vs-gerund, existentials

"There are two apartments fitting you perfectly." Is this a correct sentence? or even a good sentence construction?

Using the word "fitting" as a present participle in this sentence seems grammatically sound but it just sounds weird or uncommon, at least for me. So, is it a good sentence?

Comment: The sentence doesn't sound proper.  Let's say "There are two ideal apartments for you".

Comment: What @Khan said (the cited usage isn't very idiomatic). Note that ***to fit the bill*** is a very common expression that might well be used in this context. And although there's nothing actually "wrong" with *There are two apartments **fitting** the bill*, I think most native speakers would be more likely to say *There are two apartments **that fit** the bill*.

Answer (score 1):

English speakers would likely understand what is meant by this sentence, but it's a little vague. Saying an apartment "fits someone" could refer to the price, features, interior design, etc. It may be better to refer specifically to what about the apartments "fit" the subject perfectly.

Here are some examples of the same sentence with added detail:

> There are two apartments within your price range.
>
> There are two apartments that suit your style.
>
> There are two apartments that have your desired features.

Answer (score 0):

> So, is it a good sentence?

A "good" sentence, when the goal is to communicate a fact, is one that communicates clearly and which doesn't require the listener (or reader) to adapt to the speaker's idiosyncracies.

**fitting** there means much the same as **which fit** or **that fit**, but it is far less common than either of them in BrE and AmE in that particular usage, so **fitting** there would be sub-optimal.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, @TRomano. I'm just trying to know if the word "fitting" there is used correctly in that sentence even if it's uncommon or say, sub-optimal.